# Best user portal?

Tags: web, users

Anyone recommend a good user portal, looking to create a portal for users to provide them some self help material. Has to be REALLY simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just about any [wiki?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki_software) MoinMoin, MediaWiki, whatever...  You'll find a good comparison on Wikipedia.

Comment: What about wordpress? is that just for blogging? We have mediawiki for our own KB but I don't think its user friendly enough

Comment: I would prefer a Wiki, as internal linking is much more easier. Wordpress is a blogging software which could be (ab)used for other purposes, but where I personally feel restricted. Mediawiki is a great  system for real big wikis (i.e. Wikipedia), other systems are much easier to use (I like Moin). In the end, it's your call - setting up a test installation of Wordpress or a Wiki system is not that difficult, so you can see and maybe even let the users decide.